# How to identify spreadsheets created in Web Apps?

Tags: excel-services, powerview, owa

We've hit the snag of not being able to use PowerView with Excel Web Apps:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/excel_services__powerpivot_for_sharepoint_support_blog/archive/2014/08/06/power-view-sheets-not-rendering-in-the-browser.aspx

In order to make the decision whether to suppress OWA for xls files, we'd like to identify spreadsheets created using OWA (ie the functionality that would be lost by switching to Excel Services). Anyone know a way of doing this?